# How can I determine why my GE water dispenser is very slow?

Tags: refrigerator

I have started realizing the water flow is slow from the dispenser. I changed the filter a few times, and It is still slow. Yesterday, I checked the water connection and here is what I found:

1. The water that goes to the fridge has a lot of pressure.
2. The water that is coming from the water valve (image below) underneath the fridge has a low pressure. (This valve is visible when I took off the door panel)

How do I know if it is the solenoid or Water Valve?

[image]

Model (GSH25JSXLSS)

Comment: That's not a valve nor is it a solenoid, it's just a connector.  If the flow is being restricted by this connector, you should remove it and see if it's blocked. There *may* be a screen inside that is meant to catch debris, and it could be dirty.

Comment: I bought a Kenmore and it takes 38 seconds to fill a two cup glass. It took my old GE 15.5 seconds to do the same thing. They say all refrigerators are not the same but twice the time plus is not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

It was the filter head. I replaced it.